# Cannot Install any PHP PECL through Cpanel (WHM) or SSH

Tags: php, module, installation, centos, pecl

When I try to install a module through PHP PECL through cpanel or whm (CENTOS 6.3 x86_64 / WHM 11.34.0 (build 7) ) I always get this result:

> ERROR: `/root/tmp/pear/imagick/configure --with-imagick' failed The
>   Imagick.so object is not in
>   /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626

Here in another example with html_parse:

> ERROR: `/root/tmp/pear/html_parse/configure --with-ekhtml' failed The
>   html_parse.so object is not in
>   /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626

I have googled it, done the suggestions and always the same result.

Answer (score 0):

What library are you trying to install?

I've found mixed results using pecl on Redhat, centos, or fedora machinces if I've ever used yum to install their versions of PHP libs.  The easiest way around your issue would be to look to see if it's in the Yum repo and install it that way:

```
 yum search 'modulename'
 yum install 'packagename'
```

I usually just do a `yum search php` and scan down the list of modules.

If you want to use pecl or can't because the libraries aren't part of yum, I'd remove the natively included version and build your PHP from scratch.  You can remove PHP and related libraries installed with the distro via yum as well.

Comment: @chris try `yum search imagick`  I get a result of `php-pecl-imagick.x86_64`

Comment: @chris add either the remi or webattic repos to your yum repositories--just google remi repository.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar server setup and I needed pecl_http. Instead of using WHM (Home »
Software » Module Installers) I used command line. Simply typed: pecl install pecl_http

It should be the same for other modules like the html_parse, just change the module name, like: pecl install html_parse

Figured I'd add this for anyone else looking for this info.